# NY/NJ/CT people - Summer Streets ride in NYC, Sat 20 Aug - Who's coming?

Tags: discussion, meetup

[Summer Streets](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dot/summerstreets/html/home/home.shtml) is a huge event where New York City closes down Park Avenue from East 72nd street (by Central Park) all the way down to the Brooklyn Bridge. I know we've got some people in the NYC area. Let's get a group of Bicycles.SE people at the event!

I'll be going whether or not anyone here wants to meet up. However, based on past years, this is an amazing afternoon, where you can ride your bike with impunity on a usually-scary, car-heavy street.

Here's [the official route](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dot/summerstreets/html/route/route.shtml).

Pictures from the 2008 event:

[image: 100_7937.JPG]

[image: 100_7932.JPG]

[image: 100_7931.JPG]

[image: 100_7910.JPG]

[image: 100_7903.JPG]

The event runs from 7 to 1pm. I'd prefer we meet in Central Park somewhere, maybe at 8 or 9, but anywhere along the route would really be fine. Reply here if you're coming. (If you're not coming, please indicate why. I'm gonna keep trying to get a real-world event together if there's no interest here.)

Those of you who don't go into the city often, you can bring a folding bike on NJ Transit any time, and a regular bike on the weekends with no issue. MetroNorth makes you buy a bike permit, for a few bucks (a one-time fee). (Not sure about LIRR.)